# How to export all product sku and cateogry id in csv format runing custom script?

Tags: custom, csv, magento2.3.1, export, script

I am using Magneto2.3.1 and i need to export all product sku and cateogry id in csv format runing custom script?if anyone know and idea share code please

Answer (score 2):

You can use below script

```
<?php 

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('sku','category_ids');

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="products.csv"');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fputcsv($fp, array("SKU","Category ID"));
foreach ($collection as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $categoryIds = implode("-", $product->getCategoryIds());
    $val =array( $sku,$categoryIds);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

Better we can use below code to get required attributes from collection instead of '*'

```
<?php 

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('sku','category_ids');

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="products.csv"');

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'wb');
fputcsv($fp, array("SKU","Category ID"));
foreach ($collection as $product){
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $categoryIds = implode(",", $product->getCategoryIds());
    $val =array( $sku,$categoryIds);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply:(